# building hdf5 library with mingw on windows 7 (error unknown type name '_In_')

Tags: c++, c, windows, hdf5

I am trying to build hdf5 library with mingw on win 7.

I have downloaded the source code, extracted it and create a folder in it named "build". From cmake-gui interface, I have chosen source directory as C:\hdf5\ and build dirctory as C:\hdf5\build\ ofcourse. After adjusting optional settings, I have configured and generated a Makafile in build folder.

Here is the problem; when I run the command mingw32-make from Command Prompt mingw started to make hdf5, but after 1% part of compilation it is giving error that:

```
C:\pcl_source_dependencies\hdf5-1.8.13\src\H5.c:857:9: error: unknown type name '_In_'
 DllMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hinstDLL, _In_ DWORD fdwReason, _In_ LPVOID lpvReserved)
```

I did not climb over that bridge. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms235402%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: what should I understand from that link that you send, would you explain it..

Comment: Based on the function signature giving you trouble, \_In\_ is one of Microsoft's annotations (so that Microsoft's tools, like Visual Studio an Prefast) can keep track of whether sensitive parameters are handled correctly. Visual Studio handles those without trouble, but you could also simply #define \_In\_ to nothing (ditto for \_Out\_) to ignore the annotation completely.

Comment: Thanks Max, that one solved my problem.